# Radio button in content editable div

Tags: javascript

I have a radio button inside a content editable div. But when I click on the radio button nothing happens in Firefox and IE. But it works fine in Chrome.

What can I do to make this work in Firefox and IE?

The code is available at http://jsbin.com/uqexoy/2/edit and is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div contentEditable="true"><input type="radio" />ere er er er re </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't think a fix is going to be so straightforward, why do you need the Radio inside the content editable?

Comment: It is a form like thing that appears in my editor and the user needs to select between an couple of choices. I know that I can do this in the normal way. But before changing I need to know if this can be done in a contentEditable div.

Comment: Can you have a button that toggles between edit and interaction modes?  This seems like an issue of separation of user actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was tested to work in IE8, IE9, Chrome and Firefox. It does work, albeit rather strangely so, also in Opera, where the `input field` (in our case a `radio button`) does change it's status to `checked` (tested with JavaScript `alert(this.checked);`), however it doesn't change it's appearance to reflect that. See for a possible workaround below.

The solution for the majority of the problematic browsers is to wrap non-editable contents in a `span`, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div contentEditable="true">
    <span contentEditable="false">
      <input type="radio" />
    </span>ere er er er re 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As for the Opera part, the fact that it doesn't reflect changes to the `radio button`'s `selected` state *'should'* be possible to override by styling its two different states with CSS selectors `input[type="radio"]` and `input[type="radio"]:checked` and applying these two CSS rules only to Opera browsers. Opera seems to accept `background-color` property changes for such `radio buttons`, which doesn't make any difference in all other browsers I've tested in. This might be your way to apply Opera specific CSS rule to reflect changes to the `checked` state. Here's an example:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {background-color:gray;}
```

Other browsers will simply ignore this CSS rule. Another acceptable Opera specific rule that can be applied is `border`, but I find that of limited to no value in our case.

Comment: Yup, can someone test this in other versions of IE as well please, I can only try in IE8 at this moment, where it works OK.

Comment: Can't get it to work in Opera, though :( ... still working on it. The radio button isn't editable as expected, however it doesn't get selected properly (checked).

Comment: OK after testing with a simple JS in Opera, it appears that the radio button does get checked, but for some bizarre reason doesn't change it's appearance (appears as if it wasn't checked). This should be solvable by applying CSS rules for the `input[type="radio"]:checked` selector, though.

Comment: @TildalWave Will this work if the parent is a contentEditable iframe?. It does not work for me

Comment: @Gautham Renganathan - Yes, it does work in the `ContentEditable` `iframe` as well, I've just tested it. Not sure what you can't make to work?

Comment: @TildalWave Yes it works inside contenteditable iframe. But not on designMode="on". Anyway contenteditalbe is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

You use the contentEditable property of the DOMElement, like so

```
 <div onClick="this.contentEditable='true';"><input type="radio" />
    This is test
 </div>
```

Comment: This changes nothing in IE.

Comment: are you sure? which version of your IE?

Comment: My problem is that I have a editor present  and inside which I have radio button added and that button needs to work for me. The div needs to be editable all the time

Comment: This also makes no difference in FF 18.0.1 Windows 7